# Adobe Flex Content Disappears in IE8

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer-8

I am having an interesting bug in MSIE8, only.

I have also tested this in MSIE7, MSIE9 and Chrome and could not reproduce it in those environments.

I have a flex application which is embedded in a webpage. The application has a few top level components. One is a mx:ViewStack which contains a number of different icons. The other is a mx:Canvas which contains a number of child mx:Canvas elements (which are used as layers to hold other UIComponents).

```
<mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" id="drawing_area" borderColor="#000000" borderStyle="solid" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" width="728" x="10" height="522.8889" y="10">
  ...
</mx:Canvas>
```

The error occurs when I perform the following steps.

1. Load the page with the component
2. Let the component fully load
3. Scroll down so that the top of the flex content goes outside the bounds of IE8's content window.

When I do the above, the mx:Canvas with the border disappears. It can still be interacted with, but any content moved into one of the child elements also disappears.

In this first image you can observe my starting state, there is a border around the drawing area, and the drawing area can be interacted with.

[image: Starting State you can see the border around the drawing_area]

This second image shows the issue, after additional scrolling down. The border disappears and all UIComponents placed into the drawing_area also disappear.

[image: Ending state no border around the drawing_area]

Unfortunately IE8 is still a popular browser in the organization this was designed for.

Anyone have any clues as to what might be happening. I have tried different wmodes for flash. I am currently using window, but have tried transparent as well, and have the same issue.

Comment: Are you testing in different versions of the flash player? Is IE8 32bit, others 64bit / opposite?

Comment: Any chance we can see this in action? It's really hard to tell what's wrong without any code and/or test scenario. Which browser you are running the plugin in should not have an impact on your Flash/Flex program, if it works correctly.  In my experience, having different behavior in different browsers is most often related to performance differences: Some processes take longer to complete, and by the time a resource is accessed, it is `null` in the slower browser, but not in the faster one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have this in a publicly accessible location. All versions were using the same flash player. This was run using IETester (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). However, I was alerted to this behavior by a user who was using IE8 as installed on Windows XP. The behavior is pretty consistent, I can hang out on the web page for as long as I want, and as soon as I scroll the page down it will cause the behavior issue. Another interesting facet of this bug, is it only affects the display. I can still interact with the drawing_area, just not see it.

Comment: When you embed are you setting the wmode to 'opaque' or 'transparent'?

Comment: The current wmode is set to 'window', I had it set to 'transparent' and the same behavior was being exhibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a number of different things to get a work-around for this bug without much success.

I am using Rails on the backend and this issue is tied to only the "new" action, and does not appear on the "edit" action. Both pages use a shared partial to render the content.

Because of this I am doing browser detection using the rails gem [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser). When a user is using IE8 I provide a recommendation to upgrade. On the page that has this error occurs I am providing instructions to enter data for the required fields and then save their report. This will take the user to the "edit" action and they will be able to interact with the flash content without issue.